# Pass Through Multiple GPUs to Virtual Machine with Hyper-V

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, gpu, hyper-v

I followed this tutorial to try and pass through GPUs to a Hyper-V virtual machine:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLLcc29EZ_8

My system has two NVIDIA 1080 Ti GPUs in it; and for some reason only one of them is fully working. Both of them show up in device manager in the VM:

[image]

But in my application that utilizes the GPUs, only one shows up. Here is what I see in my Hyper-V virtual machine:

[image]

And here is what I see on the host:

[image]

As expected, when attempting to complete the GPU rendering in the VM, it only uses one of the two GPUs.

**Is there any way to pass through both of them to the VM instead of only one?**

Comment: Does your CPU and motherboard support IOMMU (Intel) or AMD-Vi (AMD) virtualization technology. This is crucial for proper GPU pass-through

Comment: @Turdie, I'm not sure how to check if it does. It is an AMD Ryzen 7950X 16-core CPU.

Comment: You can do that with PowerShell `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor | Select-Object Caption,VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled`. Look for the "VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled" property. If it's set to "True," AMD-V is enabled. If it's "False," virtualization might be disabled in the BIOS or not supported by your processor.

Comment: @Turdie, thanks, I checked and it is set to true, so yes, it is enabled.

Comment: I will answer with a PowerShell script to set everything correct for gpu pass through

Comment: You might want to update your question to reflect what causes you to believe the 2nd GPU isn't working correctly. Include which apps, the behavior you expect and the behavior you encounter.

Comment: @Amorphous, the application, which normally utilizes multiple GPUs, does not detect its presence, as presented in the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Enable Hyper-V and related features
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All

# Enable GPU DirectPath I/O (if supported by your hardware)
# Replace 'PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX' with your GPU's Vendor and Device IDs
$gpu1DeviceId = 'PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX'
$gpu2DeviceId = 'PCI\VEN_YYYY&DEV_YYYY'
Add-WindowsFeature Hyper-V-PowerShell

# Create a new VM
New-VM -Name "VMName" -MemoryStartupBytes 4GB -BootDevice VHD -NewVHDPath "C:\Path\To\VM\VMName.vhdx" -NewVHDSizeBytes 50GB

# Add both GPUs to the VM
Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(XXXX)#XXX(XXXX)"
Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(YYYY)#YYY(YYYY)"

# Configure VM for GPU passthrough
Set-VM -VMName "VMName" -AutomaticStopAction TurnOff -AutomaticStartAction StartIfRunning
Set-VMFirmware -VMName "VMName" -EnableSecureBoot Off

# Start the VM
Start-VM -VMName "VMName"

# Install GPU drivers within the VM
```